# C# code for HTML Next item button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image: Picture of example]

This is my example blog on asp.net mvc. My question is how and where to add c# code such that the NEWEST and the OLDER buttons can change to next post and to previous post ?

Comment: Why do you need C# for that?Just search for "Older" and "Newer" in your project and rename the buttons to the desired values

Comment: No I want to step into next post from the database and to previous post not to rename them !

Comment: Ok so what have you tried so far to achieve this?Rename the button text is like one of the most basic programming tasks, so which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: When I click on a post from the blog it opens in new window only the clicked post and from there I have two buttons "Next" and "Previous". I want to make them redirect to previous post and the next button to redirect to the next post if there is such post. My idea is to get the current post id and when click on next button to redirect to action method which will give me the current post id+1.

Comment: I have put a picture on the question if you haven't seen it.

Comment: For MVC, the proper way to do that is to use `ajax` at button clicks. To store Post ID, you can store previous Post ID value in a `Global Variable`..

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your viewModel to hold next and previous post ids and set them in the SinglePost action. 
Your ViewModel could look like:

```
public class SinglePostViewModel
{
    public int OlderId { get; set; }
    public int NewerId { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in the view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Older", "SinglePost",new {Id = Model.OlderId}, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
@Html.ActionLink("Newer", "SinglePost",new {Id = Model.NewerId}, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example using jQuery `$.getJSON` method, hope it helps you:

**Model:**

```
public class Article
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
    {
        List<Article> articles = new List<Article>()
        {
            new Article{ ID=1,Title="Article 1",Body="This is article 1..."},
            new Article{ ID=2,Title="Article 2",Body="This is article 2..."},
            new Article{ ID=3,Title="Article 3",Body="This is article 3..."}
        };

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Article article = articles.First();
            return View(article);
        }

        public JsonResult GoToPost(int id,string type)
        {
            int originalId = id;
            int newId = type == "Previous" ? --id : ++id;
            Article article = articles.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.ID == newId);
            if(article == null)
                article = articles.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == originalId);

            return Json(article, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model MVCTutorial.Models.Article

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var id = @Model.ID;

        $(".nav").click(function () {
            var type = $(this).val();
            $("#title").empty();
            $("#body").empty();

            var url = "/Articles/GoToPost?id=" + id + "&type=" + type;
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $("#title").append(data.Title);
                $("#body").append(data.Body);
                id = data.ID;
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input class="nav" type="button" value="Previous" />
<input class="nav" type="button" value="Next" />
<div id="title">@Model.Title</div>
<hr />
<div id="body">@Model.Body</div>
```